# Row set in 'Auto' takes me all the screen even if it is blank

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In a `CollectionView` I have 4 `rows`, 2 of which are set to "`Auto"`.
In one I have a `Label` in `Binding`, in the other I have another `CollectionView` with objects in `Binding`. In the `Row` where I have the `Label`, the height is automatically set correctly, while where I have the `CollectionView` it becomes an "infinite" height, in the sense that even if empty, it takes up the whole screen.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <yummy:PancakeView  CornerRadius="5" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
       <Grid BackgroundColor="Gainsboro" RowSpacing="0.2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="21"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="16"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" BackgroundColor="{Binding ColoreUmore}"/>
             <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding GiornoTrascritto}" FontSize="14" TextColr="Gray"  Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
             <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Orario}" FontSize="14" TextColr="Gray"/>
             <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="8" Source="{Binding Umore}" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="45"/>
             <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Nota}" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"/>

             <CollectionView
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="0,0,10,0"
                    Grid.Column="2"             
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding IconDiaries}"
                    VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
                     </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                               <Grid RowSpacing="0.5">
                                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                     <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
                                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                      <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="5" Opacity="0.6" />
                                  <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding isSource}" Margin="3"/>
                                  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="12" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
                                  </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 </CollectionView>
  </Grid>
   </yummy:PancakeView>
</DataTemplate>
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while where I have the CollectionView it becomes an "infinite" height, in the sense that even if empty, it takes up the whole screen.

From your code and description, you have one collectionview in datatemplate, now you want to adjust collectionview height according to its content, am I right?

If yes, I suggest you can **binding collectionview  HeightRequest** like the following code:

```
 <StackLayout >
        <CollectionView 
            x:Name="assessmentsCollectionView"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            HeightRequest="{Binding rowHeigth}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding letters}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="5" Spacing="10">
                        <Frame
                            Padding="0"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Frame
                                    Padding="5"
                                    CornerRadius="0"
                                    WidthRequest="50">
                                    <Label
                                        FontSize="24"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{Binding TypeLetter}"
                                        TextColor="#37474f"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </Frame>
                                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                    <Label
                                        FontSize="24"
                                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                                        TextColor="Black" />
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image
                                            HeightRequest="12"
                                            Source="c1.png"
                                            WidthRequest="12" />
                                        <Label
                                            FontSize="12"
                                            Text="{Binding Date}"
                                            TextColor="Gray" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
            Text="btn1" />
    </StackLayout>

    public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new letterviewmodel(); ;
    }
}
public class letterviewmodel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<lettermodel> letters { get; set; }
    private int _rowHeigth;
    public int rowHeigth
    {
        get { return _rowHeigth; }
        set
        {
            _rowHeigth = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("rowHeigth");
        }
    }
    public ICommand AddCommand { protected set; get; }
    public letterviewmodel()
    {
        letters = new ObservableCollection<lettermodel>()
        {
            new lettermodel(){TypeLetter="A",Name="letter 1",Date="2021-01-01"},
            new lettermodel(){TypeLetter="B",Name="letter 2",Date="2021-01-01"},
            new lettermodel(){TypeLetter="C",Name="letter 3",Date="2021-01-01"}

        };
        rowHeigth = letters.Count * 100 ;

        AddCommand = new Command<lettermodel>(async (key) => {
            letters.Add(new lettermodel() { TypeLetter = "D", Name = "test letter ", Date = "2021-01-01" });
            rowHeigth = letters.Count * 100 ;
        });
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
public class lettermodel
{
    public string TypeLetter { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It works.
But I don't understand two things:
1) If the CollectionView is empty, the Row still takes a small space for me, I don't know why, but it's acceptable.
2) Why doesn't the Label need this additional code while the CollectionView does?

Comment: @signalover the current layout behavior of CollectionView is basically the same as what ListView does (always maximally expanding, no matter what the layout options are).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the CollectionView to take an automatic height and adapt to the row, right?

In order to make this happen you will need to:

1. Set the property
   `ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"` in the CollectionView, so the CollectionView has the proper height you're looking for.
2. Set the Row Height to `*`, so the CollectionView height sets automatically for the remaining size of the page.
3. Set `VerticalOptions` to `FillAndExpand` in Collection View so the CollectionView can adapt to the size of the Row.
4. Finally, put the label with Row `3` below the CollectionView to avoid any issues with the Layout order.

Let me know if this does any help!